# Euclidean Norm of a vector function not working well due to change in data type

Tags: c, types

**N.b.** The below code is not using  intentionally

In the below code I am successfully calculating the Euclidean Norm of a vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanning_vector(int *vector);
int printing_vector(int *vector);
float euclidean_norm(int *vector);

int main()
{

    int vector1[5], vector2[5];
    float solution;

    printf("Please enter the first vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector1);
    printing_vector(vector1);
    solution=euclidean_norm(vector1);
    printf("%f",solution);


    printf("\nPlease enter the second vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector2);
    printing_vector(vector2);

    return 0;
}

int scanning_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}

int printing_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ", vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

float euclidean_norm(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    float temp, sqrt, euclidean_norm;
    temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        euclidean_norm=euclidean_norm+vector[i]*vector[i];
    }
    /* The below code is to calculate the square root without using math.h */
    sqrt = euclidean_norm / 2;

    while(sqrt != temp)
    {
        temp = sqrt;
        sqrt = (euclidean_norm/temp + temp) / 2;
    }
    return sqrt;
}
```

However, I fail to understand why the below code doesn't work. I have only changed in the `euclidean_norm` function the data type of the parameter `euclidean_norm` from `float` to `integer`. Could you give me a quick explanation as to why this is not working? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanning_vector(int *vector);
int printing_vector(int *vector);
float euclidean_norm(int *vector);

int main()
{

    int vector1[5], vector2[5];
    float solution;

    printf("Please enter the first vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector1);
    printing_vector(vector1);
    solution=euclidean_norm(vector1);
    printf("%f",solution);


    printf("\nPlease enter the second vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector2);
    printing_vector(vector2);

    return 0;
}

int scanning_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}

int printing_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ", vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

float euclidean_norm(int *vector)
{
    int i, euclidean_norm;
    float temp, sqrt;
    temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        euclidean_norm=euclidean_norm+vector[i]*vector[i];
    }
    /* The below code is to calculate the square root without using math.h */
    sqrt = euclidean_norm / 2;

    while(sqrt != temp)
    {
        temp = sqrt;
        sqrt = (euclidean_norm/temp + temp) / 2;
    }
    return sqrt;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `euclidean_norm`, which is indeterminate. Initialize that before entering the loop.

After that, the line `sqrt = euclidean_norm / 2;` should be `sqrt = euclidean_norm / 2.0f;` to avoid the result truncated to integer.

Comment: quick question: why this undefined behavior only happens when using `int`, why I don't need to initialize `euclidean_norm` when using `float` in order to get the correct result? Thank you!

Comment: Uninitialized `float` also invokes *undefined behavior*. You just got correct result by chance.

Comment: Understood. Thank you, @MikeCAT! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MikeCAT for the quick answer! Just leaving here the code that works when using the data type of the parameter `euclidean_norm` as integer. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int scanning_vector(int *vector);
int printing_vector(int *vector);
float euclidean_norm(int *vector);

int main()
{

    int vector1[5], vector2[5];
    float solution;

    printf("Please enter the first vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector1);
    printing_vector(vector1);
    solution=euclidean_norm(vector1);
    printf("%f",solution);


    printf("\nPlease enter the second vector:\n");

    scanning_vector(vector2);
    printing_vector(vector2);

    return 0;
}

int scanning_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;   
}

int printing_vector(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d ", vector[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

float euclidean_norm(int *vector)
{
    int i, euclidean_norm=0;
    float temp, sqrt;
    temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        euclidean_norm=euclidean_norm+vector[i]*vector[i];
    }
    /* The below code is to calculate the square root without using math.h */
    sqrt = euclidean_norm / 2;

    while(sqrt != temp)
    {
        temp = sqrt;
        sqrt = (euclidean_norm/temp + temp) / 2;
    }
    return sqrt;
}
```